# Save location for ALAuthorizationStatus on iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios-simulator

I'm struggling to find a way how to test my `ALAssetsLibrary wrapper framework` without creating a Test application where I have to grant access by clicking on the `YES` button of the prompt dialog for allowing access to the `Photo library`.

Where does `Apple` saves the granted permissions for an application to access the `Photo library`?

All the `UnitTests` should run without any manual interception during the first start of the test application. Even better if there would be a way to test my framework without creating an `Test UI application` to grant access for the application by hand.